# Appbar shows different sizes for the same height on different devices?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, appbar

I am facing a problem with the AppBar that has never happened to me earlier. My appbar height has different sizes in iOS and Android.

I am using a `extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,` for the Scaffold and the body is a ListView which takes the padding using the Appbar height.

I have added the pictures below to better explain what is happening.

Can someone help me?

iOS
[image: ios]

Android
[image: android]

I found on internet that it could be solved by using PreferedSize, but the widget already has preferedSize, so this solution was not working.

I tried to change multiple times the height of the AppBar, but it was working on some devices and in others not. I also tried to change the height in percentage, but neither that was working.

I also tried to get the padding from context, but the value is not the same that the list is using.

Comment: Are you using safe area widget?

Comment: Any progress?  I'm noticing that on app start up appbar is different height than hot reload or hot restart.